# Best way to create a pivot like table with date columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pivot

I have a few tables with data and I am attempting to generate a pivot like table in the following format:

```
Area  | Type | 2013-08-25 | 2013-08-26 | 2013-08-27, etc..
South | Red  |     5      |      2     |       9
North | Blue |     3      |      0     |       7
```

Currently to generate this I am using PHP to loop through each date and generate the sum(if statements for each date based upon a given start & end date.

I know I could run the query and group by date before and then assemble it in PHP but an SQL solution seems easier than that.

Is this the best way to accomplish what I am trying to do or is there another easier way I am missing?

Example Query:

```sql
SELECT 
iw.display_name as Area, 
iet.type as 'Type', 
sum(if(date(iac.created_at) = '2013-08-25',1,0)) as '2013-08-25', 
sum(if(date(iac.created_at) = '2013-08-26',1,0)) as '2013-08-26', 
sum(if(date(iac.created_at) = '2013-08-27',1,0)) as '2013-08-27', 
sum(if(date(iac.created_at) = '2013-08-28',1,0)) as '2013-08-28', 
sum(if(date(iac.created_at) = '2013-08-29',1,0)) as '2013-08-29', 
sum(if(date(iac.created_at) = '2013-08-30',1,0)) as '2013-08-30', 
sum(if(date(iac.created_at) = '2013-08-31',1,0)) as '2013-08-31',  
count(iac.id) as total 
FROM iac
JOIN ioc on ioc.id = iac.ioc_id
JOIN iet on iet.id = ioc.iet_id
JOIN iw  on  iw.id = iac.iw_id
WHERE date(iac.created_at) between '2013-08-25' and '2013-08-31'
GROUP BY iw.id, iet.id
ORDER BY iw.display_name, iet.type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is fine.  You can simplify it (because you are using MySQL) by removing the `if` conditions.  Booleans are treated as `1` for true and `0` for false:

```
SELECT iw.display_name as Area, iet.type as `Type`, 
       sum(date(iac.created_at) = '2013-08-25') as `2013-08-25`, 
       sum(date(iac.created_at) = '2013-08-26') as `2013-08-26`, 
       sum(date(iac.created_at) = '2013-08-27') as `2013-08-27`, 
       sum(date(iac.created_at) = '2013-08-28') as `2013-08-28`, 
       sum(date(iac.created_at) = '2013-08-29') as `2013-08-29`, 
       sum(date(iac.created_at) = '2013-08-30') as `2013-08-30`, 
       sum(date(iac.created_at) = '2013-08-31') as `2013-08-31`,  
       count(iac.id) as total 
FROM iac
JOIN ioc on ioc.id = iac.ioc_id
JOIN iet on iet.id = ioc.iet_id
JOIN iw  on  iw.id = iac.iw_id
WHERE iac.created_at >= date('2013-08-25') and iac.created_at < date('2013-09-01')
GROUP BY iw.id, iet.id
ORDER BY iw.display_name, iet.type;
```

I also replaced the single quotes in the column aliases with back quotes.  You should only use single quotes for string constants.

I also replaced the date logic with inequalities.  This removes the function call (`date()`) around the column, making it more likely that an index would be used for this filtering.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. A couple questions on the WHERE portion though. Is the date() required around the date strings? I would think date would be unnecessary since the string is already in a date format? The iac.created_at field is a datetime type so will MySQL assume '2013-08-25' is '2013-08-25 00:00:00' and '2013-08-31' goes to '2013-08-31 23:59:59'?

Comment: @John . . . No, the date is not required.  As for the second question,  date is equivalent to a datetime with a time of 0.  That's why the second value is an inequality one day later (I just fixed that).

Answer (score 1):

This is as good as you can get in MySql in terms of pivoting. You can simplify things for yourself (in order not to type all possible dates every time) by implementing this query using dynamic SQL and wrapping it into a stored procedure like this

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_report(IN dt_start DATE, IN dt_end DATE)
BEGIN
  SET @sql = NULL;

  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
           CONCAT('SUM(CASE WHEN DATE(iac.created_at) = ''',
           DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d'),
           ''' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) `',
           DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d'), '`'))
    INTO @sql
    FROM iac
   WHERE iac.created_at >= DATE_FORMAT(dt_start, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') 
     AND iac.created_at <= DATE_FORMAT(dt_end,   '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59') ;

  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT iw.display_name area, iet.type `type`, ', @sql, 
                    ', COUNT(iac.id) total 
                       FROM iac JOIN ioc 
                         ON ioc.id = iac.ioc_id JOIN iet 
                         ON iet.id = ioc.iet_id JOIN iw  
                         ON iw.id  = iac.iw_id
                      WHERE iac.created_at >= ', DATE_FORMAT(dt_start, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00'),  
                    '   AND iac.created_at <= ', DATE_FORMAT(dt_end,   '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59'),
                    ' GROUP BY iw.id, iet.id
                      ORDER BY iw.display_name, iet.type');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Sample usage:

```sql
CALL sp_report('2013-08-25', '2013-08-31');
```